# How to get the length of the selected word in the eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When I am checking the naming rules for my code. If i got variable or function name have more letters than allowed ERROR. I count the total character by manually or have to copy paste into Notpad++. Is there is any options to find the number of selected characters in eclipse.

Comment: What programming language is this for?

Comment: for the c programming language

Comment: It looks like CODAN can be configured to do exactly what you want. See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=263048&goto=760128&#msg_760128

Comment: No, it is just to find how many characters are selected by mouse (any pointing device). For example, in notepad++ after selecting a particular word,  in the bottom one block  will display the how many letters are selected , that feature only exactly I need for the ECLIPSE.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse does not provide a way to display the length of a text selection like NotePad++.

[Bug 73904: Show length of selection in status box](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=73094) was raised in 2004 (!!!) to add this feature but it still hasn't been implemented.

The good news is that [someone has written a plugin named **getStringLength**](https://github.com/aleroot/getStringLength) to do exactly what you want, as mentioned in a comment in the Eclipse Bug Report:

> Eclipse plugin that add the selected text counter on the right side of
>   the column and row position in the Eclipse status bar. After you
>   double click the text, this plug-in will show the length of text you
>   selected in the eclipse status bar; in the case you select more than
>   one row it will show the number of rows selected, like Notepad++ do.

The bad news is that I couldn't get it to work properly. After adding the plugin to Eclipse's **dropins** folder the status bar is updated as described, but the details are misaligned and not rendering correctly:

[image: selTextLen]

Through careful testing I can see that the plugin actually is updating the length of the selected text, but the entry on the status bar is practically illegible. Still, in the absence of anything else, it is worth trying - perhaps you will have better luck in your environment. Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: it is work fine after long days i found that It was hide behind some other plugin and remove that plugin i got that plugin, thanks

Comment: @PARTHASARATHIRavi That's good. Which plugin did you remove so that **getStringLength** worked properly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin anymore with [Eclipse 2019-09](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#editor-status-line):

> ### Editor status line shows more selection details
>
> The status line for Text Editors now shows the cursor position, and when the editor has something selected, shows the number of characters in the selection as well.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/selection-offset.png]

> This also works in the block selection mode.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/selection-count.png]

> These two new additions to the status line can be disabled via the `General > Editors > Text Editors` preference page.

Answer (score 0):

i has fixed error rendering in eclipse version=4.12.0 on windows 10, with steps.

1. clone project ([getStringLength project](https://github.com/aleroot/getStringLength.git))
2. import to

   - edit file com.lyf.plugin.getStringLength.SelectedTextInfoControlContribution.java (line 26).

     `@Override
     protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
         parent.getParent().setRedraw(true);
         ......
     }`
   - build plugin:

```
    1. Right-click your plugin project in Package Explorer window.
    2. Press Export... in shown context menu.
    3. Select Plug-In Development -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments (or Deployable plug-ins and fragments directly in old Eclipses).
    4. Close Eclipse. Copy this JAR to eclipse/plugins/ path. Run Eclipse again.
```

Good luck!